# How to edit some txt in the tab?

Tags: python, automation, powerbi, pywinauto

https://github.com/dubravcik/pbixrefresher-python/blob/master/pbixrefresher/pbixrefresher.py

I am using **pywinauto** package to automate the Power BI process.
After I get into `Edit Parameters`, can I know how to edit the text in the tabs? For example, change '1' to 'a', change '2' to 'b' and lastly change '3' to 'c'. At the end, click 'OK'. Any idea?

Part of the code I have:

```
win = app.window(title_re = '.*Power BI Desktop')

win.Home.click_input()

win.Transformdata.click_input()

win.Editparameters.click_input()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use pywinauto `set_text` function to edit the text box

Below is the sample code

```
Editable_TextBox = win.child_window(title=<UI_identifier>, control_type="Edit")
Editable_TextBox.set_text(<Text_you_set>)
```

Or You can use `type_keys` function

```
win.Editparameters.type_keys(<Text_you_need_To_set>,with_spaces=True)
```