# Edit the text in sub windows for powerbi 2020 by using pyautowin python package

Tags: python, powerbi, pywinauto

I need to edit the parameters in the edit queries sub window from 'Edit Queries'. However, once i enter the sub-window, i found no way to edit the parameters i would like to change. Help needed for that one , thanks!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEKQF.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8FO0.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmwdY.png)

Comment: Probably you need `win.dump_tree()` to find correct identifier on the whole window. Don't think it's a child of button. BTW, `dump_tree()` is a short name of `print_control_identifiers()`.

Comment: Can you also combine duplicated question (https://stackoverflow.com/q/66704736/3648361) into this one? Just edit the question and add more details. No need to post duplicates.